# Import database into another with a different name

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

This is not a question of 'how to'. I am trying to understand the role of names of databases in pHpMyAdmin--specifically in relation to how to connect the database(s) to locally installed WordPress.

A lot of instructions on importing databases via MAMP say to create a new database first in PhPMyAdmin (and name it whatever one wants). But when I import a database, it retains its old name, AND (seemingly) exists parallel to the newly created database (which I thought was where the data would be imported into).

While experimenting with re-naming the imported database, I saw some information (such as users) seemed to remain despite the re-naming.

So which name is the database associated with--the name displayed in the pHpMyAdmin? the name of the new database created for importing but empty after the import?

Comment: If you rename a database within phpMyAdmin (in the database "Operations" tab), privileges are adjusted so user permissions are moved to the new name (there's a checkbox for this functionality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new WordPress system, you copy the **wp-config-sample.php** file to **wp-config.php** and then modify the settings in **wp-config.php**.

The first settings you come to are the MySQl settings. Here you put in your **database name** (DB_NAME), **database username** (DB_USER), **user's database password** (DB_PASSWORD), the **host** (DB_HOST) and the **character set** (DB_CHARSET).

When you save the configuration file and launch WordPress for the first time, **it will use whatever database you have specified in the wp-config.php**.

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: In pHpMyAdmin, I see both the database I created (for the import) and the database that got imported--they are listed as equals. Are they connected? So is there need to keep the empty database I created?

Comment: You only need to keep the database that you enter into the wp-config.php.